# Why is AWS ALB not talking to an ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm taking TechnoWorld Kubernetes Administration class, where we learn to create a Kubernetes cluster from scratch using one Ubuntu EC2 for master node, and two Ubuntu EC2s for worker nodes. The course guides us into installing the different Kubernetes components - containerd, kubeadm, kubelet, kubectl, Weavnet etc. - on each pertinent EC2. We use NGINX as our simple application that are running on our worker node pods. I have the infrastructure set up where I can actually, for example, do a `curl <pod IP address>` from my master node and get the "Welcome to nginx" greeting as a response. So far so good. I even created a Terraform script to set this up. I even setup test Kubernetes LoadBalancer service that's accessible to the outside world, put it's `IP:port` on the browser and see "Welcome to nginx" proving that the networking (VPC, subnet, security group) is correct.

Here's the traffic flow of the **fundamental** infrastructure we're trying to build.

Internet-facing AWS ALB(port 80) -> ingress controller LoadBalancer service(port 80:32111 mapping) -> ingress -> ClusterIP service -> EC2 worker with NGINX pod

So a user puts an ALBs DNS name on the browser and gets the "Welcome to NGINX" greeting.

However with my setup, when I put the ALB's DNS name, I get a "This site can't be reached" message.

I set up my internet-facing ALB to serve port 80, forward to a target group on port 32111 (ingress controller port) that has the 2 EC2 worker nodes registered as targets.

Any pointers on how I can debug this seemingly simple/fundamental setup?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is running and working fine on AWS, the key pieces of information you mentioned above are the DNS record and the Ingress.

I would assume you have defined the [Ingress Name based virtual hosting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting).

Then you'd also need to add, in AWS Route53, the appropriate DNS records to point the the ALB.